# Word for Not No?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the semantic not(no), as one word.

I'm exploring languages through orthography. I can easily identify the opposite of yes as no. Is there a word for *not no*?

Comment: As a Southerner, there's not no reason to need one. [No one gets to see the Wizard](https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5249691/il_570xN.34767635.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean "neither yes nor no"?  If not, can you explain more about the difference between what you want and the word "Yes", which intuitively seems like the answer to "not(no)".

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct English equivalent for the French *si* or the German *doch*. Instead English resorts to simply using *yes*. As do many other languages, mind you.

Comment: in English, all you can do is say "yes" and hope your meaning is clear, or say "not no" to be explicit (but sound odd).

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of: [Answering a negative question with one word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161262/answering-a-negative-question-with-one-word)

Some languages have three-form or four-form systems allowing precise, one word answers for negative questions. For example, the German word "doch" would fit as "not no".

Unfortunately, Modern English doesn't really have a suitable equivalent.
I say *sutiable* because there is a word many of us used colloquially as children to mean not no: "Yeah-huh"

"You're not coming to Billy's party?"

"Yeah-huh!"

Answer (score 1):

> Paul does not like chocolate. Neither does Andrew. (= also no)
>
> Paul does not like chocolate. Andrew *does*. (= not no)

or

> Jane has not got any brothers or sisters. Neither has Mary. (= also no)
>
> Jane has not got any brothers or sisters. Mary *has*. (= not no)

or

> – You did not keep your promise!  – I *did* keep it! (= not no)

etc.

Using an emphasized positive auxiliary to respond to a negative statement does the trick of "not-noing"!